# What is the name of this learning algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I designed a learning algorithm for an AI player that tries different methods of winning the game and then continues on with method that has the highest win rate. If the highest win rate method starts to lose it goes onto the method with the 2nd highest win rate etc...

I need to do a write up on the learning algorithm, what could it be called?

Comment: It's your algorithm; how about naming it after yourself? Selection the option with the highest expected utility is quite common in AI but it doesn't really have a name as such. MinMax is applicable in a more specific context (tree structure with two players).

Comment: I believe you need to look into **game theory**, not machine learning.

Comment: It depends if you consider code feminine or masculine. Im thinking a Clarissa or a Billy

Comment: Though if your code throws a lot of exceptions consider Steve. Steve has been known to cause people exceptional problems

Comment: What's wrong about "user2951186's algorithm"?

Comment: how about the 'naive pragmatist'?

Answer (score 5):

The algorithm has no name because its not particularly good (no offense) relative to what exists for such problems.

What you are "solving" is the [Multi-armed Bandit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit) problem. The "different methods of winning" are your slot machines, and your "win rate" is the payout odds of each slot machine. Because you are playing against another person and they might change their strategy, you must deal with the possibility that the best slot machine might "start to lose". This is an adversarial scenario. There are many papers and algorithms on this topic from many different perspectives / scenarios. Its very well studied and people are still interested in it.

I assume this is for some class project report. I would simply call it "My heuristic approach", because that is what it is.

Answer (score 1):

It's a classical Try & Error approach. TryError, TryAndError, TaE, Try&Error-o-matic, pick whatever you like more.

Answer (score 1):

That probably depends on how you have implemented it. It sounds a little like a multi-class logistic regression algorithm. This evaluates the probability of a given outcome for each of the classes and then chooses the best probability, but this could also be implemented with neural networks or various other algorithms.